# Каталога не существует, хотя он есть

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я создаю на python telegram бота Remote Controller (пульт управлением фильмами на ноутбуках). Я недавно переходил с одного компьютера на другой и у меня возникла ошибка в боте (если что на старом была ubuntu, на новом kubuntu). Бот по идее, когда я нажимаю кнопку, должен выпадать список фильмов, которые есть в папке. В боте происходит такой процесс, что с помощью функции os.listdir() он получает список файлов в папке, потом бот этот список выводит, как inline кнопки, если нажмешь на одну из кнопок откроется фильм. Я посмотрел ошибку, дело в том что он не может получить этот список, то есть говорит: "Каталога не существует". Таким образом я попробовал вставить другую папку, но все равно не получилось. Помогите, пожалуйста! Вот мой код главного файла:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
#Подключаем нужные библиотеки
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from config import bot_token, admin
import murkup as nav

#создаем объекты и первоначальные переменные
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
os.system("amixer -c 0 set Master 80%")
v = 80

#Приветствие по команде старт
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def command_start(mes: types.Message(admin)):
    await bot.send_message(mes.from_user.id, "Привет!", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(mes: types.Message(admin)):
    global v
    # Регулируем громкость
    if mes.text == "➕":
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id-2)
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id-1)
        v += 2
        os.system(f"amixer -c 0 set Master {v}%")
        await bot.send_message(admin, f"Громкость: {v}%", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
    if mes.text == "➖":
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id-2)
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id-1)
        v -= 2
        os.system(f"amixer -c 0 set Master {v}%")
        await bot.send_message(admin, f"Громкость: {v}%", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
    # Промотка вперед и назад
    if mes.text == "⏩":
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id)
        os.system( "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek int64:10000000")
    if mes.text == "⏪":
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id)
        os.system("dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek int30:10000000")
    # Побольше экран экран
    if mes.text == "↕️":
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id)
        os.system("dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.fullscreen")
    # Выбор фильма
    if mes.text == "Выбрать фильм":
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id)
        await bot.send_message(admin, "Выберете фильм", reply_markup=nav.choice())
    #Пауза и пуск
    if mes.text == "⏯":
        os.system("qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause")
        await bot.delete_message(mes.from_user.id, mes.message_id)
        await bot.send_message(admin, "Фильм либо остановлен, либо включен.", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="/")
async def open_m(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    os.system(f"xdg-open <path{call.data}>")
    await bot.send_message(admin, "Фильм включен. Приятного просмотра! ", reply_markup=nav.mainMenu)
    await bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id,call.message.message_id)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Код файла, который нас больше всего интересует:

```py
import os
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton,InlineKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton
# Основное меню
# Кнопки изменения громкости
btnP = KeyboardButton('➕')
btnM = KeyboardButton("➖")
btnV = KeyboardButton('⏩')
btnN = KeyboardButton("⏪")
btnF = KeyboardButton("↕️")
# Пауза
btnPause = KeyboardButton("⏯")
# Кнопка перехода на другое меню
btnChoice = KeyboardButton("Выбрать фильм")
# Отоброжение кнопок основного меню
mainMenu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(btnM,btnP,btnF,btnN,btnPause,btnV,btnChoice)
# Меню выбора фильма
def choice():
    lis = os.listdir(path='file:///home/user/Загрузки')
    choiceMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for i in lis:
        choiceMenu.insert(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"{i}",callback_data=f"/{i}"))
    return choiceMenu
```

Ошибка:

[image]

Очень хочу возобновить своего бота.

Comment: А что происходит, если `listdir` дать просто абсолютный путь папки без URI (убрать `file://`)?

Comment: Я это пробовал. Но сначала не работало потому, что название файлов были длинные. Исправил и помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: Вот ссылка на бота: https://github.com/Johnny-kiv/Remote-controller. Он сделает ваш просмотр фильмов комфортнее.